# MATLAB time stamps reading

Tags: matlab, datetime, file-io, timestamp

Any easy way to read all the columns in MATLAB?

my format is

```
date  time    y1   y2  y3   y4 .........................      
4/27/2010  00:3:09   34  45  45 56 ................
```

so on... Currently i am reading these with the code:

```
[c,pathc]=uigetfile({'*.txt'},'Select the data','C:\Data');    
file=[pathc c];     
data= dlmread(file, ',', 1,3);
```

so needless to say i am skipping the time stamps.

Was wondering if there is easy way to read the time stamps and plot my other columns against the time  in hours.

my files are  43200 X 30 and some are 86400 X 90

Related question : is the format same for .csv and .xls files , i mean except of course xlsread

Answer (score 1):

I already answered to your question on the same data here:
[skip reading headers in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588021/skip-reading-headers-in-matlab/2588353#2588353)

```
[c,pathc]=uigetfile({'*.txt'},'Select the data','C:\Data');
file=[pathc c];
A = importdata(file, ' ', 1);
dt = datenum(A.textdata(2:end,1),'mm/dd/yyyy');
tm = datenum(A.textdata(2:end,2),'HH:MM:SS');
tm = dt+tm-datenum('0:0','HH:MM'); %# combine date and time and correct for zero time.
data = A.data;
```

You can plot your data against `tm` and use [DATETICK](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/datetick.html) function to show date in any format.

```
plot(tm,data)
datetick('x','HH')
xlabel('Time, hours')
```

---

**EDIT**

You can also use [Jonas's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588021/skip-reading-headers-in-matlab/2588565#2588565) for previous question to read the data. Then do same as above:

```
dt = datenum(dateAndTimeCell(:,1),'mm/dd/yyyy');
tm = datenum(dateAndTimeCell(:,2),'HH:MM:SS');
tm = dt+tm-datenum('0:0','HH:MM');

plot(tm,dataArray,'o-')
datetick('x','HH')
xlabel('Time, hours')
```

Comment: i get whole bunch of error and i do not understand them

??? Error using ==> dlmread at 145
Mismatch between file and format string.
Trouble reading number from file (row 1,
field 5) ==> :00:0

Error in ==> dlmread at 90
        result=
        dlmread(filename,delimiter,r,0);

Error in ==> testwith_timestamps at 45
data= dlmread(file, ',', 1);
 
??? Error using ==> importdata at 199
Unable to load file.

Comment: Use TEXTSCAN or FREAD for more complex
formats.
Error in ==> testwith_timestamps at 49
A = importdata(file, ' ', 1);
Caused by:
    Error using ==> vertcat
    CAT arguments dimensions are not
    consistent.

Comment: I used the same code as yours after my uiget command  minus the dlmread i used as ur code imports the data

Comment: You cannot use dlmread to read non-numeric data. Dates are actually strings in the file. And use space as a separator, not comma. With dlmread you have to skip not only one row, but 2 left columns.

Comment: It still gives me datenum errors

??? Error using ==> datenum at 174
DATENUM failed.

Error in ==> testwith_timestamps at 51
dt =
datenum(A.textdata(2:end,1),'mm/dd/yyyy');

Caused by:
    Error using ==> dtstr2dtnummx
    Failed on converting date string to date
    number.

Comment: Are you sure all rows have the same format? Any missing data? Check the A variable after importdata.

Comment: Do you have repeated headers as you described in the previous question?

Comment: They have the same format and no missing data. also i doubt i can use this as i compare data from different dates and each files are like 50mbs long. This way it just crashes.

I have checked and picked files which do not have repeated headers. Thats a another problem and i am not including that here

Comment: I edited the answer. Check if the other solution will help. Are you sure the dates format is always correct and correspond to datenum statements?

Answer (score 0):

I believe sscanf will do the trick for you.